# Importing 3D models with Assimp is not working

Tags: c++, assimp

I am trying to read different 3D formats using [Assimp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Asset_Import_Library). My corresponding C++ code looks like this:

```
void loadScene(string myFile)
{
    Importer importer;
    const aiScene *scene = importer.ReadFile(myFile, 0);
    if(scene) cout<<"OK"<<endl;
    else cout<< importer.GetErrorString () <<endl;
}

int main()
{
    loadScene("myFile.fbx");
    loadScene("myFile.3ds");
    loadScene("myFile.obj");
    loadScene("myFile.glb");

    return 0;
}
```

And the output:

```
OBJ: Invalid face indice
OBJ: Invalid face indice
OK
OBJ: Invalid face indice
```

Can this be fixed? All four files, I am trying to read are OK. I checked them with some 3D viewer.

I checked the reason for that problem is because Assimp always selects the importer for obj format. The simplest solution would be to force Assimp explicitly to use the right importer, since I know exactly which importer is suitable for which file. Unfortunately it seems like Assimp has no way to select importer explicitly.

So I just added this code:

```
const std::string::size_type s = pFile.find_last_of('.');
if (s != std::string::npos) {
     unsigned int a = GetImporterIndex(_pFile+s);
     imp = pimpl->mImporter[a];
}
```

to `const aiScene* Importer::ReadFile( const char* _pFile, unsigned int pFlags)` and my output looks like this:

```
OK
Chunk is too large
OK
GLTF: Unsupported binary glTF version
```

The problem with the glb file seems to be because the wrong importer is used. It should be gltf2, but gltf is used instead.

Comment: `BaseImporter* Assimp::Importer::GetImporter(const char * szExtension) const` looks promising

Comment: OK thanks will try it. Does that BaseImporter has also some kind of read function?

Comment: http://assimp.sourceforge.net/lib_html/namespace_assimp.html

Comment: @Passerby Is this documentation stil actual? Asking because it´s fro 2012 and for version 3.0.

Comment: Hi @convert did you find any solution to load .fbx files?

Comment: @Faris Mohamed Yes, just have to edit some Assimp code to find the right importer.

Comment: okay cool, can you share some snippets?